# Location of Server Document Root for Bitnami Ghost AWS Install

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-ec2, ghost

I have just installed Ghost Powered by Bitnami for an Amazon Web Service EC-2 instance.

I'm trying to figure out where to place fonts so that they are in the "root" of my webpage. E.g: `myhost.com/fonts/`.

I know that Apache has its server document root in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`, but files I place there doesn't seem to be reachable. I'm not sure if I'm at the right place or not.

Since the instance is for the Ghost platform, going to the URL takes me to the Ghost page. I'm not sure if Apache needs to be activated or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a directory under `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`, for example `/fonts`.
2. Place your files in that directory
3. Edit `/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/conf/httpd-app.conf` and add `ProxyPass /fonts !` (mind the exclamation mark) in a line after `ProxyPass /bitnami !`
4. Restart apache: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Help from: https://community.bitnami.com/t/location-of-root-www-folder-for-bitnami-ghost-install/38478